# How to update a column of table for bulk records using namedParameterJDBCTemplate batchUpdate?

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, namedparameterjdbctemplate

I want update a column of table for bulk records. How can i do that using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

```
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList();
ids.add(1);
ids.add(2);

String updateQuery = "update product set status = 'P' where id = ?";
SqlParameterSource  batch = SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(ids.toArray());

namedParameterJDBCTemplate.batchUpdate(updateQuery, batch)
```

However, the above is not working. Please advise

Comment: You are using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` but are not using named parameters. Another thing which is important is which database are you using? Finally could you be more clear on **what** isn't working? No batch update? No updates at all?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` but are not using names in your query. You should have something like this.

```java
Map<String, Long> row1 = Map.of("id", 1L);
Map<String, Long> row2 = Map.of("id", 2L);

SqlParameterSource  batch = SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(List.of(row1, row2);

String updateQuery = "update product set status = 'P' where id = :id";
namedParameterJDBCTemplate.batchUpdate(updateQuery, batch)
```

or don't use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` but just a regular `JdbcTemplate`.

```java
List<Object[]> ids = List.of(new Object[] {1L}, new Object[] {2L});
String updateQuery = "update product set status = 'P' where id = ?";
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(updateQuery, ids)
```

or, if the list of ids isn't too large use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` with an `IN` clause instead of a batch update.

```
List<Long> ids = List.of(1L, 2L);

String updateQuery = "update product set status = 'P' where id in (:ids)";
namedParameterJDBCTemplate.update(updateQuery, Map.of("ids", ids));
```

Comment: HI, Thank for your quick response. Which one is the fastest, i will be updating around 8k records

Comment: Measure I suspect the plain `JdbcTemplate` one as that doesn't involve String parsing to replace the placeholder with question marks. The `IN` one is out the the question then (as those are limited generally to somewhere around 1000 entries). If you have that many you want to use an `InterruptibleBatchPreparedStatementSetter` to determine the optimal batch size (maybe that is 8K but it could be smaller as well).

Comment: But that basically is another question, this one was about the fact it wasn't working which was due to the wrong usage. Which this answer does actually explain and cover.

Comment: String updateQuery = "update product set status = 'P' where id in (:ids)";
namedParameterJDBCTemplate.update(updateQuery, Map.of("ids", ids));  -> I am getting ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

Comment: As I stated **"as those are limited generally to somewhere around 1000 entries:** and I also stated that with 8K items you cannot use the `IN` clause.